# Alternative to Database Change Notification (DCN)

Tags: database, spring-boot, oracle12c

I am working on a Springboot project which needs a database listener that listens to any change made to a table in Oracle database (12c).

Oracle's Database Change Notification (DCN) seems to be the perfect solution.

But a quick research concluded that Oracle 12c (which we are using) doesn't support Database Change Notification (DCN). The Database Registration seems to be working as we can print the table being registered for listening.
But the onDatabaseChangeNotification method of the class implementing DatabaseChangeListener interface isn't being called when the table is updated.

[Why should we not upgrade to Oracle 12c……YET](https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/why-should-we-not-upgrade-to-oracle-12c-yet/)

There are other restrictions in the requirement - No manually created threads, no triggers in DB are used.

I have used example shown in this Oracle guide. (minus the synchronization part and thread creation in onDatabaseChangeNotification method of listener class)==>
[Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816)

Is there any working alternative to this?.

Comment: If it does not work, you should contact Oracle support. Moreover it looks like it only does not work with pluggable databases, which is a new 12c feature.

Comment: Can you please let us know which version of Oracle 12c is used at your end?

Comment: Did you grant 'change notification' to the user?
'grant change notification to user1'